# Google charts - Plot trendlines on column chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, jsapi

I am trying to plot trendline on column chart. But lines not displaying. 
Please refer jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sashant9/m04py64w/

I have used 'trendlines: { 1:{},2:{}}' as per google charts documentation.

Please check code below.

```
    function drawVisitorGraph() {


        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Search Visitors');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Unique Visitors');

        data.addRow(["2015-07-01",1774,3266]);
        data.addRow(["2015-07-02",1891,3017]);
        data.addRow(["2015-07-03",1572,2730]);
        data.addRow(["2015-07-04",979,1604]);
        data.addRow(["2015-07-05",1024,1702]);
        data.addRow(["2015-07-06",2163,4097]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.querySelector('#visitor_graph'));

        var options = {
                bars: 'vertical',
                vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
                trendlines: { 1:{},2:{}}, 
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                colors: ['#070979', '#EC0F13']
            }
            chart.draw(data,options);

    }

    //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawVisitorGraph});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below code, Check working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m04py64w/2/).

```
function drawVisitorGraph() {


    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Search Visitors');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Unique Visitors');

    data.addRow([new Date(2015,07,01),1774,3266]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2015,07,02),1891,3017]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2015,07,03),1572,2730]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2015,07,04),979,1604]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2015,07,05),1024,1702]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2015,07,06),2163,4097]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.querySelector('#visitor_graph'));

    var options = {
            bars: 'vertical',
            vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
            trendlines: { 0:{},1:{}}, 
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            colors: ['#070979', '#EC0F13']
        }
        chart.draw(data,options);

}

//google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawVisitorGraph});
```

Comment: thnx for response, we want a cury line something like this https://jsfiddle.net/sashant9/m04py64w/1/, but x-axis should be date type, could u plz help.

Comment: To generate a polynomial trendline, specify type polynomial and a degree. Use with caution, since they can sometimes lead to misleading results. Here for example i use a cubic (degree 3) trendline.

`trendlines: { 0:{type: 'polynomial', degree: 3}, 1:{type: 'polynomial', degree: 3}}`